# Extending an isomorphism between subfields of an algebraically closed field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

Let $k$ and $k'$ be subfields of an algebraically closed field $\ell$, and suppose $\sigma: k \mapsto k'$ is an isomorphism of fields. When can $\sigma$ be extended to an automorphism of $\ell$ (upon accepting the axiom of choice) ?